# Suddenly ALL my references in .bib file go ??? in text citation

Tags: bibtex

I think there's something wrong with my bib file. it seemed like it was working fine until now, when I deleted my old .aux, .out and .bbl file and compiled my .tex again. I don't know what else to do, it was working just now.

My .bib file must have at least 50 references and none of them is working:

```
@article{kuhara1996vocalization,
  title={Vocalization latencies of skilled and less skilled comprehenders for words written in hiragana and kanji},
  author={Kuhara-Kojima, Keiko and Hatano, Giyoo and Saito, Hirofumi and Haebara, Tomokazu},
  journal={Reading Research Quarterly},
  volume={31},
  number={2},
  pages={158--171},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{carson1992becoming,
  title={Becoming biliterate: First language influences},
  author={Carson, Joan G},
  journal={Journal of Second Language Writing},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={37--60},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{samimy1994teaching,
  title={Teaching Japanese: Consideration of learners’ affective variables},
  author={Samimy, Keiko Komiya},
  journal={Theory into Practice},
  volume={33},
  number={1},
  pages={29--33},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}


@article{bull1996karuta,
  title={Karuta: Sport or culture?},
  author={Bull, David},
  journal={Japan Quarterly},
  volume={43},
  number={1},
  pages={67},
  year={1996},
  publisher={Asahi Shimbun}
}

@article{marciano2013karucha,
  title={Karuch{\=a} Ships Invaders: cultural issues on the design/development of a Japanese CALL game made by/to Brazilians},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and Ferreira, Alessandro Luiz Stamatto and Correia, ACC and Miranda, LC and Miranda, EEC},
  journal={Anais do XII Simp{\'o}sio Brasileiro de Jogos e Entretenimento Digital},
  pages={172--180},
  year={2013},
  publisher={SBC}
}


@article{marciano2015evaluating,
  title={Evaluating multiple aspects of educational computer games: literature review and case study},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and Miranda, Leonardo Cunha de and Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha de},
  journal={International Journal of Computer Games Technology},
  volume={2014},
  pages={14--14},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Hindawi Limited London, UK, United Kingdom}
}



@inproceedings{marciano2012japanese,
  title={Japanese language learning supported by computational tools: State of the art and challenges for the Latin America community},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha},
  booktitle={2012 XXXVIII Conferencia Latinoamericana En Informatica (CLEI)},
  pages={1--10},
  year={2012},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{marciano2016karucha,
  title={Karucha Ships Invaders em Sala de Aula: Relato de Experi{\^e}ncia do Uso do Jogo Educacional por Estudantes de Japon{\^e}s do IFRN},
  author={Marciano, Juvane and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha and de Oliveira, Paulo de Tasso Ribeiro},
  booktitle={Anais do XXII Workshop de Inform{\'a}tica na Escola},
  pages={555--564},
  year={2016},
  organization={SBC}
}

@inproceedings{marciano2013android,
  title={Android MALL apps for Japanese language: identifying and eliciting interface/interaction requirements through the semiotic framework},
  author={Marciano, JN and Miranda, LC and Miranda, EEC and Pereira, R},
  booktitle={XXXIX Conferencia Latinoamericana en Inform{\'a}tica},
  pages={220--230},
  year={2013}
}

@inproceedings{marques2018assessment,
  title={Assessment of Lexical Acquisition of a Student with High Japanese Language Proficiency: An Analysis Based on Nihongo Kotoba Shiken},
  author={Marques, F{\'a}bio Andrews Rocha and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha},
  booktitle={2018 XIII Latin American Conference on Learning Technologies (LACLO)},
  pages={216--223},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{marques2018nihongo,
  title={Nihongo Kotoba Shiken: a computerized exam of Japanese lexical proficiency},
  author={Marques, F{\'a}bio Andrews Rocha and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha},
  booktitle={2018 XLIV Latin American Computer Conference (CLEI)},
  pages={398--407},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@inproceedings{marciano2013japanese,
  title={Japanese CALL web tools: identifying and evaluating their multimedia behaviour in android OS},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Miranda, Erica EC},
  booktitle={EdMedia+ Innovate Learning},
  pages={1087--1096},
  year={2013},
  organization={Association for the Advancement of Computing in Education (AACE)}
}
@article{zaibon2010mobile,
  title={Mobile Game-Based Learning (mGBL): Application development and heuristics evaluation strategy},
  author={Zaibon, Syamsul Bahrin and Shiratuddin, Norshuhada},
  journal={Malaysian Journal of Learning and Instruction (MJLI)},
  volume={7},
  number={2010},
  pages={37--73},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Universiti Utara Malaysia Press}
} 

@article{moreno2018design,
  title={Design of a checklist for evaluating language learning websites},
  author={Moreno Fuentes, Elena and Risueno Martinez, Jesus J and others},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Universidad de Granada}
}

@article{ishaq2021heuristics,
  title={Heuristics and think-aloud method for evaluating the usability of game-based language learning},
  author={Ishaq, Kashif and Rosdi, Fadhilah and Zin, Nor Azan Mat and Abid, Adnan},
  journal={International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications},
  volume={12},
  number={11},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Science and Information (SAI) Organization Limited}
}

@inproceedings{mohamed2010heuristics,
  title={Heuristics evaluation in computer games},
  author={Mohamed, Hasiah and Jaafar, Azizah and others},
  booktitle={2010 International Conference on Information Retrieval \& Knowledge Management (CAMP)},
  pages={188--193},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{kim2012exploring,
  title={Exploring smartphone applications for effective mobile-assisted language learning},
  author={Kim, Heyoung and Kwon, Yeonhee},
  journal={Multimedia-Assisted Language Learning},
  volume={15},
  number={1},
  pages={31--57},
  year={2012}
}

@article{hubbard1988integrated,
  title={An integrated framework for CALL courseware evaluation},
  author={Hubbard, Philip},
  journal={CALICO journal},
  pages={51--72},
  year={1988},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{hubbard2006evaluating,
  title={Evaluating CALL software},
  author={Hubbard, Philip},
  journal={Calling on CALL: From theory and research to new directions in foreign language teaching},
  pages={313--338},
  year={2006},
  publisher={CALICO San Marcos}
}

@article{hubbard2011evaluation,
  title={Evaluation of courseware and websites},
  author={Hubbard, P},
  journal={Present and future promises of CALL: From theory and research to new directions in language teaching},
  pages={407--440},
  year={2011},
  publisher={CALICO San Marcos, TX}
}

@article{govender2021analysis,
  title={An analysis of game design elements used in digital game-based language learning},
  author={Govender, Terence and Arnedo-Moreno, Joan},
  journal={Sustainability},
  volume={13},
  number={12},
  pages={6679},
  year={2021},
  publisher={MDPI}
}

@article{sykes2018digital,
  title={Digital games and language teaching and learning},
  author={Sykes, Julie M},
  journal={Foreign Language Annals},
  volume={51},
  number={1},
  pages={219--224},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{butler2014online,
  title={Online games for young learners’ foreign language learning},
  author={Butler, Yuko Goto and Someya, Yuumi and Fukuhara, Eiji},
  journal={Elt Journal},
  volume={68},
  number={3},
  pages={265--275},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Oxford University Press UK}
}

@article{traxler2009current,
  title={Current State of Mobile Learning. Mobile Learning: Transforming the Delivery of Education and Training},
  author={Traxler, J},
  journal={URL: http://www. aupress. ca/index. php/books/120155 (04.02. 2020)},
  year={2009}
}

@incollection{kukulska2013design,
  title={Design principles for mobile learning},
  author={Kukulska-Hulme, Agnes and Traxler, John},
  booktitle={Rethinking pedagogy for a digital age},
  pages={268--281},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Routledge}
}

@incollection{ang2008computer,
  title={Computer games and language learning},
  author={Ang, Chee Siang and Zaphiris, Panayiotis},
  booktitle={Handbook of research on instructional systems and technology},
  pages={449--462},
  year={2008},
  publisher={IGI Global}
}

@article{kacetl2019use,
  title={Use of smartphone applications in english language learning—A challenge for foreign language education},
  author={Kacetl, Jaroslav and Kl{\'\i}mov{\'a}, Blanka},
  journal={Education Sciences},
  volume={9},
  number={3},
  pages={179},
  year={2019},
  publisher={MDPI}
}

@article{xu2020scoping,
  title={A scoping review of digital game-based technology on English language learning},
  author={Xu, Zhihong and Chen, Zhuo and Eutsler, Lauren and Geng, Zihan and Kogut, Ashlynn},
  journal={Educational Technology Research and Development},
  volume={68},
  pages={877--904},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{macedonia2005games,
  title={Games and foreign language teaching},
  author={Macedonia, Manuela},
  journal={Support for learning},
  volume={20},
  number={3},
  pages={135--140},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{godwin2014games,
  title={Games in language learning: Opportunities and challenges},
  author={Godwin-Jones, Robert},
  year={2014},
  publisher={University of Hawaii National Foreign Language Resource Center}
}

@article{ciampa2014learning,
  title={Learning in a mobile age: an investigation of student motivation},
  author={Ciampa, Katia},
  journal={Journal of Computer Assisted Learning},
  volume={30},
  number={1},
  pages={82--96},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{wang2021developing,
  title={Developing English language learners’ oral production with a digital game-based mobile application},
  author={Wang, Zehua and Han, Feifei},
  journal={Plos one},
  volume={16},
  number={1},
  pages={e0232671},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA}
}

@inproceedings{edge2011micromandarin,
  title={MicroMandarin: mobile language learning in context},
  author={Edge, Darren and Searle, Elly and Chiu, Kevin and Zhao, Jing and Landay, James A},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the SIGCHI conference on human factors in computing systems},
  pages={3169--3178},
  year={2011}
}

@article{haristiani2016android,
  title={Android application for enhancing Japanese JLPT N5 kanji ability},
  author={Haristiani, Nuria and Firmansyah, Dian Bayu},
  journal={Journal of Engineering Science and Technology},
  volume={12},
  pages={106--114},
  year={2016}
}

@article{elaish2019development,
  title={Development of a mobile game application to boost students’ motivation in learning English vocabulary},
  author={Elaish, Monther M and Ghani, Norjihan Abdul and Shuib, Liyana and Al-Haiqi, Ahmed},
  journal={IEEE Access},
  volume={7},
  pages={13326--13337},
  year={2019},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{perry2015gamifying,
  title={Gamifying French language learning: A case study examining a quest-based, augmented reality mobile learning-tool},
  author={Perry, Bernadette},
  journal={Procedia-Social and Behavioral Sciences},
  volume={174},
  pages={2308--2315},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{udjaja2022game,
  title={Game-based Learning Increase Japanese Language Learning through Video Game},
  author={Udjaja, Yogi and Suri, Puti Andam and Gunawan, Ricky Satria and Hartanto, Felix},
  journal={International Journal of Advanced Computer Science and Applications},
  volume={13},
  number={2},
  year={2022},
  publisher={Science and Information (SAI) Organization Limited}
}

@inproceedings{marciano2015katakana,
  title={Katakana Star Samurai: A mobile tool to support learning of a basic Japanese alphabet},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and de Oliveira, Jaime Bruno Cirne and de Menezes, Bruna Camila and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha},
  booktitle={2015 Latin American Computing Conference (CLEI)},
  pages={1--8},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{marciano2014applying,
  title={Applying the Method for Evaluation of Motivational Aspects on Karuch{\=a} Ships Invaders Educational Game with Brazilian Students of Japanese},
  author={Marciano, Juvane Nunes and de Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha},
  booktitle={Anais do XX Workshop de Inform{\'a}tica na Escola},
  pages={66--75},
  year={2014},
  organization={SBC}
}

@inproceedings{marques2015sumo,
  title={Sumo Sensei: Design, implementa{\c{c}}{\~a}o e teste com usu{\'a}rios de uma ferramenta m{\'o}vel para apoiar o estudo de kanjis b{\'a}sicos},
  author={Marques, F{\'a}bio Phillip Rocha and de Menezes, Bruna Camila and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Miranda, Erica Esteves Cunha and Marciano, Juvane Nunes},
  booktitle={2015 Latin American Computing Conference (CLEI)},
  pages={1--12},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{torat2000computer,
  title={Computer-assisted language learning: An overview},
  author={Torat, Bamrung},
  journal={Silpakorn University International Journal},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={131--153},
  year={2000}
}

@article{miangah2012mobile,
  title={Mobile-assisted language learning},
  author={Miangah, Tayebeh Mosavi and Nezarat, Amin},
  journal={International Journal of Distributed and Parallel Systems},
  volume={3},
  number={1},
  pages={309},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Citeseer}
}

@book{csikszentmihalyi2000beyond,
  title={Beyond boredom and anxiety.},
  author={Csikszentmihalyi, Mihaly},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Jossey-bass}
}

@book{csikszentmihalyi1991flow,
  Author = {Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi},
  Title = {Flow: The Psychology of Optimal Experience},
  Publisher = {Harper \& Row},
  Year = {1990},
  ISBN = {0060162538},
  URL = {https://www.amazon.com/Flow-Psychology-Experience-Mihaly-Csikszentmihalyi/dp/0060162538?SubscriptionId=AKIAIOBINVZYXZQZ2U3A&tag=chimbori05-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=0060162538}
}

@book{csikszentmihalyi1993evolving,
  title={The evolving self: A psychology for the third millennium},
  author={Csikszentmihalyi, Mihaly},
  volume={5},
  year={1993},
  publisher={HarperCollins Publishers New York}
}
%%a partir daqui, são os não testados por bugs


@inproceedings{marques2015karuta,
  title={Karuta Kanji: Jogo educacional para estudar e praticar vocabul{\'a}rio com Kanjis da lingua japonesa},
  author={Marques, F{\'a}bio Andrews Rocha and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha and de Menezes, Bruna Camila and others},
  booktitle={2015 Latin American Computing Conference (CLEI)},
  pages={1--13},
  year={2015},
  organization={IEEE}
}



@inproceedings{marques2022Design,
  title={Design de Jogo e Experi{\^e}ncia de Fluxo: Reflex{\~a}o e Desafios na Perspectiva da Teoria do Fluxo},
  author={Marques, F{\'a}bio Phillip Rocha and de Miranda, Leonardo Cunha},
  booktitle={2022 Simpósio Brasileiro de Jogos e Entretenimento Digital (SBGames’22)},
  pages={1--10},
  year={2022},
  organization={IEEE}
}








@article{rego2015heeg,
  title={Heeg: Heuristic evaluation for educational games},
  author={R{\^e}go, MBBAB and de Medeiros, Igor},
  journal={Proceedings of SBGames},
  year={2015}
}





@article{sakamoto1976writing,
  title={Writing systems in Japan},
  author={Sakamoto, Takahiko},
  journal={New horizons in reading},
  pages={244--249},
  year={1976},
  publisher={ERIC}
}



@article{sung2015effective,
  title={How effective are mobile devices for language learning? A meta-analysis},
  author={Sung, Yao-Ting and Chang, Kuo-En and Yang, Je-Ming},
  journal={Educational research review},
  volume={16},
  pages={68--84},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}



@incollection{whitton2009learning,
  title={Learning and teaching with computer games in higher education},
  author={Whitton, Nicola},
  booktitle={Games-Based learning advancements for multi-sensory human computer interfaces: Techniques and effective practices},
  pages={18--33},
  year={2009},
  publisher={IGI Global}
}
```

And my main .tex file is now huge, and none of the citations is working. I don't know if I can post it here.

My log file for compilation warns me that all citations are undefined:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsuc7hdismcz8uz/sbc-sample.log?dl=0

Comment: you have tagged both bibtex and biblatex (biber) which are you using? Latex never reads the `.bib` file you need to run bibtex or biber to generate the references

Comment: You are using `natbib` not `biblatex` according to your log, is this correct? We cannot help nor debug without seeing a minimal example of your code that produces your issue, don't just copy and paste your "huge" main.tex here, cut the code down to the bare minimum please

Comment: if you are using natbib run pdfltex then bibtex then pdflatex twice.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle says: Rerun bibtex, to generate again the bbl file that you have deleted. You have to rerun Bibtex each time you either change the bib file(s), or delete the bbl file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my probelem: using  texMaker, i had to FIRST OF ALL set my .tex file as the "master document" (that was why I was getting compilation errors), then compile my .tex, compile my .bib, then compile my tex 2 times again. PHEW!